# How to duplicated or drop the row with condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have unbalanced data frame, I try to make data balanced first before unstack data, the key point is `len(df.Question == "Q007_C02")` is number of row of new data, so if any levels of `df.Question` greater than number of row of `df.Question == "Q007_C02"`, I take only the first row to `len(df.Question == "Q007_C02")`, if `df.Question` smaller than number of row of `df.Question == "Q007_C02"`, I need to duplicated, then unstack data or transpose.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Question":["Q007_A00","Q007_B00","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C02","Q007_C02","Q007_C02","Q007_C02","Q007_C02"],
               "Key": ["Y","N",1,4,5,2,8,9,3,"Text 1","Text 2","Text 3","Text 4","Text 5"]})
df

    Key Question
0   Y   Q007_A00
1   N   Q007_B00
2   1   Q007_C01
3   4   Q007_C01
4   5   Q007_C01
5   2   Q007_C01
6   8   Q007_C01
7   9   Q007_C01
8   3   Q007_C01
9   Text 1  Q007_C02
10  Text 2  Q007_C02
11  Text 3  Q007_C02
12  Text 4  Q007_C02
13  Text 5  Q007_C02
```

You can see `len(df.Question == "Q007_C02")` = 5, so use 5 as default of number of row of data frame, my desired out put.

```
  Q007_A00  Q007_B00    Q007_C01    Q007_C02
0   Y          N            1        Text 1
1   Y          N            4        Text 2
2   Y          N            5        Text 3
3   Y          N            2        Text 4
4   Y          N            8        Text 5
```

Comment: What is balanced?

Comment: Sorry confused you, the length of each level of variable "Question" equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that works for your sample data.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Question":["Q007_A00","Q007_B00","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C01","Q007_C02","Q007_C02","Q007_C02","Q007_C02","Q007_C02"],
               "Key": ["Y","N",1,4,5,2,8,9,3,"Text 1","Text 2","Text 3","Text 4","Text 5"]})

#create a new index column which based on which row each item should occupy in the balanced table
df = df.sort_values('Question')  #the dataframe must be sorted for this to work
new_index = []
for c in df.groupby('Question')['Key'].count():
    new_index.extend(range(c))
# for the example code, new_index is this list [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

balanced = df.set_index([new_index, 'Question']) #set the dataframe index to have two levels, index and Question
balanced = balanced.unstack()                    #unstack on the last index level, which is Question
balanced.columns = balanced.columns.droplevel(0) #the column index is a MultiIndex of (Key, Question), remove the top level
balanced = balanced.dropna(subset=['Q007_C02'])  #limits the dataframe to the number of rows in column Q007_C02
balanced = balanced.fillna(method='ffill')       #fill missing values based on the last valid value
```

The key to using `unstack()` was creating an index with the values of the rows of each entry in the balanced dataframe. The `for` loop creates this new index based on the `count()` of `df.Keys` for each `df.Question`. Once you have this index, the rest is manipulating the dataframe to get the desired structure.

I have a feeling that there may be a better way to get the index, but I just can't think of it now.